# Login prompt does not appear after editing /etc/fstab

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, centos, fstab

I am currently using CentOS 6.4. I've added 4 entries to the /etc/fstab to auto mount 4 disk.

```
/dev/sdc1    /usr/bin    ext4    defaults    0 2
/dev/sdc2    /usr/sbin   ext4    defaults    0 2
/dev/sdc3    /usr/lib64  ext4    defaults    0 2
/dev/sdc4    /home       ext4    defaults    0 2
```

It has been 1 hours since I've rebooted the box after editing the fstab file, but, the login prompt still does not appear?

Comment: Did you install your OS with that setup, or at least copy over stuff from your original `/usr/*` to your new partitions?  Without doing either of those, you won't be able to start without all of those being either copied from the origin -or- fixed.  Fixing it may require a live cd boot to edit the fstab file.  Can you justify why you did that - it isn't a problem if it is designed that way (allbeit, a little odd in my experience).

Answer (score 2):

You mounted stuff over some very critical directories, so the binaries your system is looking for to start the login console, and to start almost everything else, are probably not where they should be. Why do you want those directories to be separate mount points?

Comment: Is it even possible to boot a system without / being an actual partition?